# Make virtual host, htaccess or php.ini or http.conf or etc?

Tags: .htaccess, php, vhosts

I want to make a blog system.
A popular blog address looks like
`blogname.sitename.com`.

I think that this address should redirect to something like
`sitename.com/index.php?user=blogname`.

Because is not logical that make a subdomain for every blog.
Is that correct?

So, I write this code for `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mail).mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mail).mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mydomain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?option=user&id=$2 [R=301,L]
```

But it does not work.
I guess that I should do some configuration another where.

Where is the configuration source?
What is the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

use $2 instead of %2

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?user=$2 [R=301,L]
```